# textview to pdf using a button

Tags: java, android, textview, itext

I have a simple project, but it is complicated when I want to extract the contents of TextView and generate a pdf.
For what I read using the iText Libreri but i dont know how deploy the code to convert the contents of my textview to pdf.
I would appreciate your help

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView nombreUsuario;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        nombreUsuario = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.tvNombreUsuario);
        nombreUsuario.setText("Claudio");
        nombreUsuario.getText().toString().trim();

    }

     //button onClick
    public void convertirToPdf(View view)
    {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
nombreUsuario.getText().toString().trim();
```

Place this line inside your convertirToPdf() method as:

```
String data = nombreUsuario.getText().toString().trim();
```

Comment: Im compiling to see if I work,I did it this way :

   public void convertirToPdf(View view)
    {
     String data = nombreUsuario.getText().toString().trim();
     
     try {
       
      Document document = new Document();
       
      PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("HelloWorld.pdf"));
       
      document.open();
       
      document.add(new Paragraph(data));
       
      document.close();
         }catch (Exception e) {
           
          System.out.println(e);
           
          }
    }

Comment: i have this error 11-16 14:37:55.581: E/InputDispatcher(68): channel '406a0ae8 com.example.itextexample/com.example.itextexample.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!

Comment: Are you using android 2.3 emulator?? Also put up the whole stack trace.

Comment: i dont understand ¿Also put up the whole stack trace?, im use 2.3.3  api10

Comment: Change your target android version. Try android 3.0, i believe the above error is a bug in 2.3 according to http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12987